# Rails 2 public folder: No route matches assets

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, apache, ruby-on-rails-2

I am working on a legacy Ruby on Rails application which is running under Ruby 1.9 and Rails 2.3.18.

I am serving the application through Apache with Passenger.

I am getting errors in the production.log which indicate that there is something wrong with how Rails or the web server is treating the public folder, e.g.

```
ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/javascripts/picnet.table.filter.min.js" with    {:method=>:get})
```

All the required assets which are causing the errors are in the application public folder.  **Note that this is under Rails 2 not Rails 3 or 4.**

My Apache host entry for the application looks like this:

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:443>
    SSLEngine on
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
    SSLCipherSuite HIGH:MEDIUM:!aNULL:!MD5
    SSLCertificateFile "/Users/evanbrown/Documents/apache-keys/server.crt"
    SSLCertificateKeyFile "/Users/evanbrown/Documents/apache-keys/server.key"
    ServerAdmin me@localhost
    DocumentRoot "/Users/evanbrown/Documents/bl-app/public"
    ServerName blapp.localhost
    ServerAlias blapp.localhost
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/localhost-error.log"
    PassengerRuby "/Users/evanbrown/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p547@rails2/wrappers/ruby"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/localhost-access.log" common
    <Directory "/Users/evanbrown/Documents/bl-app/public">
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Options -MultiViews
        PassengerAppEnv production
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

The application is being served correctly by Passenger but since all the stylesheets and Javascripts in the public folder are causing routing errors, the output is all wrong.

I have read lots of posts that state that a misconfigured config.serve_static_assets can cause these problems but this seems to be for Rails 3 only as there is no option serve_static_assets under config in Rails 2.

My public folder is owned by the Apache user and group, which I understand is _www:_www under OS X.

```
-rwxrwxrwx   1 _www  _www    947  5 Nov 11:20 404.html
-rwxrwxrwx   1 _www  _www    930  5 Nov 11:20 422.html
-rwxrwxrwx   1 _www  _www    948  5 Nov 11:20 500.html
-rwxrwxrwx   1 _www  _www      0  5 Nov 11:20 favicon.ico
-rwxrwxrwx   1 _www  _www  14571  5 Nov 11:20 favicon.png
drwxrwxrwx   4 _www  _www    136  5 Nov 11:20 images
drwxrwxrwx  11 _www  _www    374  5 Nov 11:20 javascripts
-rwxrwxrwx   1 _www  _www    204  5 Nov 11:20 robots.txt
drwxrwxrwx   4 _www  _www    136  5 Nov 11:20 stylesheets
```

Can anyone help me to find out what the solution to this problem is?  Many thanks for your help.

Comment: I think the problem might be that you don't need those paths in quotes

Comment: I have removed the quotes and I still get the same errors.